# Plotting a next value using linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I constructed a linear regression model to fit a dataset, now I would like to see how a new value is positioned with respect to the previous prediction.
this is the code

```
X = dataframe.iloc[:,1].values.reshape(16, 1)
y = dataframe.iloc[:, -1].values.reshape(16, 1)
Xb = np.hstack((np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X))
print(Xb)
theta = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(Xb.T, Xb)), np.dot(Xb.T, y))
preds = np.dot(Xb, theta)
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, preds, color='red', lw=2)
plt.xlabel('Gross National Product [GNP]')
plt.ylabel('Number of people employed')
```

X and y are numpy ndarray of floats.

Comment: And what is not working? It looks to me that `plot(X,preds)` would be the regression line?

Comment: Everything s working, I would like to pass a value to this prediction and watch how it's positioned  on the regression, tell me if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 1):

For the function `a*x+b=y` you have estimated `a` and `b` in `theta`. You already calculated based on `a` and `b` the predictions, namely matrix `Xb` contains your `x` value and `1` (dot product is x times a (first element of theta) and 1 times b).

Thus what you have todo is to create a new `Xb` matrix with for example 1 row (if you only want 1 new point).

So if you have `Xb = np.array([10, 1]) your predilection would be on` x=10`. Maybe you have to change the shape a little bit, but I do not have your data so I cannot test if this work directly for your case, but this is what you have to do to calculate new predictions.

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(0, 5, 6) # array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
Y = 2*X + 3 # array([ 3.,  5.,  7.,  9., 11., 13.])
Xb = np.vstack((X, np.ones(X.shape[0]))).T
theta = np.linalg.inv(Xb.T@Xb)@Xb.T@Y # array([2., 3.]) (note 2, 3 from how we calculated Y)
# I used another format (@ is a dot product) but it is the same as:
theta = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(Xb.T, Xb)), np.dot(Xb.T, Y))

# Now a new prediction at X=15:
# we know 2*15+3 = 33
X_pred = np.array([15, 1])
y_pred = X_pred@theta # 33

# matrix form makes it possible to do multiple predictions at once, but you can also use:
y_pred = 15 * theta[0] + theta[1] # 33

# but if you want to predict on X = [15, 20, 25]:
X_pred = np.array([15, 20, 25])
# add ones (b component)
X_pred = np.vstack([X_pred, np.ones(X_pred.shape)]).T
y_pred = X_pred @ theta # array([33., 43., 53.])
```